# Socket tests pass locally but fail in a Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, bitbucket

Here's the method I'm testing:

```
    public Socket initSocket(String[] possibleHosts, int port) {
        for(String host : possibleHosts) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(host, port);

                LOG.info("initSocket(): Successfully initialized socket with host: " + host);

                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("initSocket(): Failed to initialize socket with host: " + host, e);

            }
        }

        return socket;
    }
```

When the method is invoked, it's not known which hosts are up so it checks all of them. Here are the tests:

```
class StompSocketTest extends Specification {

    @Subject
    def stompSocket = new StompSocket()

    def "Should initialize a socket with the first host"() {
        given:
        String[] possibleHosts = [ "localhost", "wrongHost" ]
        def port = 80

        when:
        def result = stompSocket.initSocket( possibleHosts, port )

        then:
        result.getInetAddress().getHostName() == "localhost"
        result.getPort() == 80
    }

    def "Should initialize a socket with the second host"() {
        given:
        String[] possibleHosts = [ "wrongHost", "localhost" ]
        def port = 80

        when:
        def result = stompSocket.initSocket( possibleHosts, port )

        then:
        result.getInetAddress().getHostName() == "localhost"
        result.getPort() == 80
    }

}
```

The tests pass locally but they fail in a Bitbucket pipeline:

```
result.getInetAddress().getHostName() == "localhost"
|      |
null   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getInetAddress() on null object
```

I suspect it has something to do with "localhost" not being a proper name for a host in the pipeline environment. However, I have no idea how to fix the issue so that it passes both locally and in the pipeline.

Comment: 80 is a privileged port. Try 8080

Comment: `result` is null, you should check why. I guess the port 80 is already in use on the server

Comment: @tgdavies Same problem.

Comment: As @Jens suggests, you'll need to find out why result is null.